# Using the $wpdb in wordpress to run SQL commands

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I created a simple update command to update a database entry. I want to be able to run any sql statement and update my wordpress database:

```
<?php    
global $wpdb;
$sql = "UPDATE tablename SET column1='testdata' WHERE id=1";
$results = get_results($sql); ?>
```

or

```
$results = query($sql);
```

No matter what I do I get the error:

Fatal error: Call to a member function get_results() on null in C:\MAMP\htdocs\new\samplesql.php on line 4

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
<?php    
include_once("wp-config.php");
include_once("wp-includes/wp-db.php");

$sql = "UPDATE tablename SET column1='testdata' WHERE id=1";
$results = $wpdb->get_results($sql);
```

You need to include the files where the database object is defined.

Comment: I see, it works for me too. I'm surprised I didn't find this mentioned in the function documentation. Anyway thanks a lot!

Comment: I did a lot of research to find an easy way and code that really works. The code you wrote is great and works well. My WordPress is version 6

Answer (score 12):

The get_results() and query() functions only work when combined with the $wpdb global.

For example:

```
global $wpdb;
$wpdb->get_results($sql);
```

Answer (score -1):

Here is a complete Example.

```
global $wpdb;
$sql = 'SELECT p.post_title FROM wp_posts as p WHERE p.post_status = %s';
$vars = ['publish'];
$result = $wpdb->get_results( $wpdb->prepare($sql, $vars) );
```

Answer (score -3):

I like to create a WordPress Page Template and then I don't have to load up any required WordPress files. The WordPress framework is loaded already.

Create a new file in your theme directory, name it something like "template-phpwork.php" and then in the file, the contents will be:

```
<?php /* Template Name: Custom PHP Work */ 

?>
```

And you can place your code in that file.

Create a new WordPress Page, and choose the "Custom PHP Work" Template.

Then publish and view your page and you can reload it as much as you need to accomplish your custom code needs.

Comment: Please share more details. You haven't event mentioned how to execute SQL statements in your answer